# Feature merging in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, merge, features

I want to merge these two features into one (N.B: One polygon shapefile, lots of features). But an error occurred.

Any possible solution please?

QGIS version: 2.14.20

[image]

Comment: I think readers will need more information in order to help you. What is the error message? What tool are you using to merge? What is the size of the files you are merging?

Comment: First of all it would be good, if you updated your QGis at least to the newest LTR. Second, all that Kingfisher said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you getting an error message? Or, by "error", do you just mean you've merged the features but can still see the edge/boundary between them?

If it's the latter, try deleting the vertices that are on the edge between the two features, leaving only a single shared segment. Then, enable snapping and be sure the vertices at the ends of that segment (the corners where your features will join) are snapped together.